# GitLab ci unpublish npm package

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

How to unpublish npm package from the npm package registry in GitLab. Iam trying to unpublish it in a job in the GitLab pipeline using :

```
- npm unpublish --force "@scope/name@1.0.0" --registry https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PR_ID/packages/npm/ --userconfig .npmrc
```

but it's not working! I don't get any error but the package still exists

Comment: Same problem here :(

Comment: any updates? I've the same issue

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_TOKEN" "https://GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/packages?order_by=version&sort=desc"
```

You will get there the package id

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_TOKEN" "https://GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/packages/PACKAGE_ID"
```